# How To Save a IShellLibary

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

The following code adds a folder to Libaries, but it does not save it:

```
function SHAddFolderPathToLibrary(const plib: IShellLibrary;
  pszFolderPath: LPCWSTR): HResult;
{ Corrected per discussion at StackOverflow }
var
  psiFolder: IShellItem;
begin
  Result := SHCreateItemFromParsingName(pszFolderPath, nil, IID_IShellItem,
    psiFolder);
  if Succeeded(Result) then
  begin
    Result := plib.AddFolder(psiFolder);
  end;
end;

function AddFolderToLibrary(AFolder: string): HRESULT;
{ Add AFolder to Windows 7 library. }
var
  plib: IShellLibrary;
begin
  Result := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLibrary, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IShellLibrary, plib);
  if SUCCEEDED(Result) then
  begin
    Result := SHAddFolderPathToLibrary(plib, PWideChar(AFolder));
  end;
end;

function RemoveFolderFromLibrary(AFolder: string): HRESULT;
{ Remove AFolder from Windows 7 library. }
var
  plib: IShellLibrary;
begin
  Result := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLibrary, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IShellLibrary, plib);
  if SUCCEEDED(Result) then
  begin
    Result := SHRemoveFolderPathFromLibrary(plib, PWideChar(AFolder));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: So, where to you want to save the library?

Comment: Do you have to save it somewhere in particular?  I'd just like the added folder to appear in Libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`IShellLibrary.SaveInKnownFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd391725.aspx). Like this:

```
uses
  Winapi.KnownFolders;

var
  hr: HRESULT;
  plib: IShellLibrary;
  si: IShellItem;
....
// your code to create plib is just fine
hr := plib.SaveInKnownFolder(FOLDERID_Libraries, 'My New Library', 
  LSF_MAKEUNIQUENAME, si);
```

For the sake of completeness, here is a minimal example:

```
program W7LibraryDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, 
  System.Win.ComObj, 
  Winapi.KnownFolders, 
  Winapi.ActiveX, 
  Winapi.ShlObj;

procedure Main;
var
  sl: IShellLibrary;
  si: IShellItem;
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLibrary, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IShellLibrary, sl));
  OleCheck(sl.SaveInKnownFolder(FOLDERID_Libraries, 'My New Library',
    LSF_MAKEUNIQUENAME, si));
end;

begin
  try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Is it ok to do this: OleCheck(sl.SaveInKnownFolder(FOLDERID_Libraries, 'Library', LSF_MAKEUNIQUENAME, si)); ?

Comment: Yes it is. Why do you think it might not be?

Comment: I just did not want to have a 'Libaries' and a 'My New Libary'... this is all new ground for me...

Comment: You can call the thing anything you like. I had to pick something, and that's what popped into my head.

Comment: Why did you use OleCheck instead of the way I did it?

Comment: So that any errors get converted into exceptions and so that you don't need deeply nested if statements. It's up to you how you handle errors.